# AWS S3 bucket endpoint points to a deleted bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My goal is to host a static website, at (not literally) faulty.com

- I've bought the domain name faulty.com using Route 53
- I've named my bucket faulty.com
- faulty.com bucket has the necessary files for a static website

I have certainty that I have correctly assembled and configured the bucket for a static website, as I have repeated the list above for (not literally) correct.com

The endpoint for the correct.com bucket displays the static website, however the **problem** is that endpoint for the faulty.com bucket attempts to redirect to another S3 bucket that I deleted previously.

The difference between the two buckets is that faulty.com has some history:

1. I created a bucket called experiment, as a static website, (no problems)
2. I created a bucket called faulty.com, to redirect to experiment
3. The host name for faulty.com couldn't get to experiment (I cannot recall why)
4. I deleted those two buckets
5. I tried to recreate faulty.com to host a static website (no redirection), however redirection still gets attempted by its endpoint

My assumption is that some information has not been deleted properly (echoing faulty.com's "bad history"). How could this be resolved? Is some sort of extensive deletion in S3 possilble?

Comment: There is possible updation of route53 entry take more time. and if you are using CloudFront then have you invalidated cache ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 I haven't touched CloudFront yet. My mistake, I did forget to state here how I tried setting up a record of faulty.com in Route 53, though I deleted it as a part of troubleshooting. Maybe then, in summary, something in Route 53 didn't get deleted "properly"?